# Return a String from a Windows Batch file

Tags: node.js, batch-file, jenkins-pipeline

I want to find the target branch when a pull request is submitted on GitHub, in my Jenkins pipeline. To achieve this I am doing the following:

I am invoking a windows batch file from my Jenkinsfile, which in turn invokes a nodejs script. This script internally invokes GitHub APIs to get the target branch which is to be set on some variable in Jenkinsfile(code snippet given below):
Jenkinsfile

```
env.TARGET_BRANCH = bat "GetTargetBranchFromGit.bat ${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
```

BatchFile:

```
node getTargetBranchForPR.js %1
```

But unfortunately, the variable env.TARGET_BRANCH is not getting set to the target branch even though the nodejs script gets the right value. I am in fact not able to return the value from the batch file. Could someone please help me here?

Comment: test to see if you can have the value echoed to screen, before the node line, do `echo %* &` and add `pause` below it.

Comment: you rather need to check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36547680/how-to-do-i-get-the-output-of-a-shell-command-executed-using-into-a-variable-fro

Comment: @npocmaka This will definitely help me in achieving what I want, but I am not able to find the git command to retrieve the target branch(base) of a commit.

Comment: I am trying to get the target branch in the JenkinsFile. I have checked lot of sites and links, but not able to find a way of getting that information.

Comment: check if the git command is in the %path% variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@npocmaka mention is the right way: [How to do I get the output of a shell command executed using into a variable from Jenkinsfile (groovy)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36547680/how-to-do-i-get-the-output-of-a-shell-command-executed-using-into-a-variable-fro)

Accodring to [Jenkins' documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#bat-windows-batch-script).

> returnStdout (optional) If checked, standard output from the task is
>   returned as the step value as a String, rather than being printed to
>   the build log. (Standard error, if any, will still be printed to the
>   log.) You will often want to call .trim() on the result to strip off a
>   trailing newline.

So your code should look like

```
env.TARGET_BRANCH = bat( script: "GetTargetBranchFromGit.bat ${env.BRANCH_NAME}",
                         returnStdout: true
).trim()
```

If you get back more than expected you probably need to parse it.

Comment: This one turned out to be a bit complex than i expected. Anyone knows any other way of finding out the target branch when a pull request is opened(in JenkinsFile)? I have a multibranch pipeline and i would want to have different behaviours based on source and the target branch.